# What is std::numeric_limits<T>::digits supposed to represent?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, c++14

I am writing an integer-like class that represents a value that lies somewhere in a range. For instance, the value of `bounded::integer<0, 10>` is somewhere in the range [0, 10]. For this class, I have defined `radix` to be `2`.

What should the value of `digits` be for `bounded::integer<-100, 5>`?

What about `bounded::integer<16, 19>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the standard a bit more and thinking about this, I believe I have the best answer, but I am not certain.

First, the definition of `digits`, taken from the latest C++14 draft standard, N3797, § 18.3.2.4:

> `static constexpr int digits;`
>
> 8 Number of `radix` digits that can be represented without change.
>
> 9 For integer types, the number of non-sign bits in the representation.
>
> 10 For floating point types, the number of `radix` digits in the mantissa

The case of `bounded::integer<-100, 5>` is the same as for `bounded::integer<0, 5>`, which would give a value of `2`.

For the case of `bounded::integer<16, 19>`, `digits` should be defined as `0`. Such a class cannot even represent a 1-bit number (since `0` and `1` aren't in the range), and according to 18.3.2.7.1:

> All members shall be provided for all specializations. However, many values are only required to be meaningful under certain conditions (for example, `epsilon()` is only meaningful if `is_integer` is `false`). Any value that is not "meaningful" shall be set to 0 or false.

I believe that any integer-like class which does not have `0` as a possible value cannot meaningfully compute `digits` and `digits10`.

Another possible answer is to use an information theoretic definition of digits. However, this is not consistent with the values for the built-in integers. The description explicitly leaves out sign bits, but those would still be considered a single bit of information, so I feel that rules out this interpretation. It seems that this exclusion of the sign bit also means that I have to take the smaller in magnitude of the negative end and the positive end of the range for the first number, which is why I believe that the first question is equivalent to `bounded::integer<0, 5>`. This is because you are only guaranteed 2 bits can be stored without loss of data. You can potentially store up to 6 bits as long as your number is negative, but in general, you only get 2.

`bounded::integer<16, 19>` is much trickier, but I believe the interpretation of "not meaningful" makes more sense than shifting the value over and giving the same answer as if it were `bounded::integer<0, 3>`, which would be `2`.

I believe this interpretation follows from the standard, is consistent with other integer types, and is the least likely to confuse the users of such a class.

To answer the question of the use cases of `digits`, a commenter mentioned radix sort. A base-2 radix sort might expect to use the value in `digits` to sort a number. This would be fine if you set `digits` to `0`, as that indicates an error condition for attempting to use such a radix sort, but can we do better while still being in line with built-in types?

For unsigned integers, radix sort that depends on the value of `digits` works just fine. `uint8_t` has `digits == 8`. However, for signed integers, this wouldn't work: `std::numeric_limits<int8_t>::digits == 7`. You would also need to sort on that sign bit, but `digits` doesn't give you enough information to do so.

Comment: "The second number, `ranged_integer<16, 19>` is much trickier," The question I'd ask is *what is `digits` used for*? For example, you could use it in a radix sort. I'd expect that `digits` provides all necessary information; yet it doesn't for your `ranged_integer`s. I cannot store a 3-digit number in `ranged_integer<16,19>` and a radix-sort on the first 3 digits would yield wrong results.

Comment: @DyP I was referring to the order in the question. I will edit my answer to make that more clear, so you don't have to jump back and forth. Answering your radix-sort example will take a little more space than I think I have in a comment, so I will edit that response in, too.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-thinking it. There are two simple options for `digits` specializations for your own `ranged_integer`

- `log2(Last-First)` when you are representing the range `[First, Last)`.
- the value of `N * numeric_limits<U>::digits` which corresponds to the smallest underlying storage `std::array<U, N>` in which you can store your range.

Note that your class `ranged_integer` can internally do a transformation to map a range of e.g. `[-100, 5]` onto `[0, 105]` so that you don't have to worry about sign-bits etc.